# How to handle substring on a changing string variable

Tags: c#, sql, row

I am currently developing an Excel reader, that is inserting into a database. Things have been going smoothly untill I stumbled on some variation in the Excel sheet.

100 rows, somehwere in the middle of the sheet, have a different style than the rest of the sheet, and my substring fails.

To give some clarification here are how they usually look:

```
DMK.2003602
DMK.4663501
DMK.3307301
etc.
```

To get the number I use a `substring` on the column in the row like this

```
row[12].ToString().Substring(4).ToString());
```

Pretty simple. However at some point it changes to this

```
82AVG.A410201
```

And my substring does not work and I get a type error when insertion to the database.

Any clue on how to handle such a change during the loop of rows?

Here is my loop,

```
foreach (var row in albums)
            {
                if (row.ItemArray.Length == 33 && row.ItemArray[0].ToString() != ""
                                              && row.ItemArray[1].ToString() != ""
                                              && row.ItemArray[2].ToString() != ""
                                              && row.ItemArray[3].ToString() != ""
                                              && row.ItemArray[4].ToString() != ""
                                              && row.ItemArray[5].ToString() != "")
                {
                        Order ord = new Order(      
                        1, 
                        maxTrNo +1,
                        row[6].ToString().Substring(row[6].ToString().Length - 5).ToString(),
                        1,
                        numVal,
                        row[13].ToString(),
                        "",
                        row[12].ToString().Substring(4).ToString()); //This is where it fails
                        orders.Add(ord);
                        maxTrNo++;

                }
            }
```

Comment: What you want from `Substring()` in cases of `82AVG.A410201` ?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that, 
I need the chars after .
so in this case, A410201

Comment: Is the type error because you are trying to put `A410201` in a integer field or do you just needs to find where in the string lies the dot?

Comment: the field i am inserting the A410201 into is a varchar so i dont think that is the problem. I just need the chars after the dot, if that makes sense.

Comment: use the IndexOf method of string to get the Position of the dot, and take the substring from this postion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.IndexOf('.')` to get the characters after the dot,

```
string s = row[i].ToString();
string afterDot = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('.' + 1));
```

To handle the case when there is no dot

```
int dot = s.IndexOf('.');
string afterDot = dot == -1 ? string.Empty : s.Substring(dot + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to get the part of string after '.', you can use (assuming you want empty string in cases of 'DMK2003602' or 'DMK2003602.')

```
var str = "DMK.2003602";
var subStr = str.IndexOf('.') > -1 && str.IndexOf('.') < str.Length -1 ? str.Substring(str.IndexOf('.') + 1) : string.Empty;
```

But for the database insertion error, there might be some other reason.